# JSON.Stringify() force int value javascript(node.js)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

Good day everyone i've been trying to force the data of my Json.stringify to int because on my mongodb it returns as string so on my schema i need to do it like this first

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    influenceid:{
        type:String
    },
    question:{
        type:String
    },
    amount:{
        type:String //i need this to be a type:Number instead of string
    }
});
```

and on my **dialog.js** where in i put the json data

```
 socket.emit('dollar quest', JSON.stringify(result[0]), 
 JSON.stringify(result[1]), inUserId, myuserid, 'dquest');
```

and on my server i fetch data like this to throw it to my mongodb

```
socket.on('dollar quest', function(dolquest,dolamnt,uid,stud,stat){
    var info = new InfoUser({
        username: stud,
        amount: dolamnt,
        question: dolquest
    });

    InfoUser.createUser(info,function(err,user){
        if(err)throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });
});
```

But the output on my mlab is like this

> **"username": "stsam1",**
>
> **"amount": "\"12500\"",**
>
> **"question": "\"how are you\"",**

How can i turn my amount into type:Number so that it will return on my mlab as like this

> **"amount": 12500,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dig this one and it works on me so i'll answer my own question but thank you for the help sir T.J and Shaib. Here's what i did.

```
 socket.emit('dollar quest', JSON.stringify(result[0]), 
 JSON.stringify(result[1]), inUserId, myuserid, 'dquest');
```

and added

```
 socket.emit('dollar quest', JSON.stringify(result[0]), 
 JSON.stringify(result[1]).replace(/\"/g, ""), inUserId, myuserid, 'dquest');
```

So the idea was replacing so Sir TJ was has the right idea

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a [*replacer* function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) to `JSON.stringify` which will convert the value to number when the key name is `"amount"`:

```
function theReplacer(key, value) {
    return key === "amount" ? +value : value;
}
```

then

```
var json = JSON.stringify(yourObject, theReplacer);
```

```js
function theReplacer(key, value) {
    return key === "amount" ? +value : value;
}
var object = {
    username: "a",
    influenceid: "b",
    question: "c",
    amount: "42"
};
var json = JSON.stringify(object, theReplacer, 2);
console.log(json);
```

That example will convert the value of **any** `"amount"` field to a number, but you can refine it if you need to limit that.

Comment: but my JSON.Stringify(result[1]) is my dolamnt on my server and on my schema when i try to change it to type:number is doesn't work and doesn't return an error why is that??

Comment: @TheGinxx009: "dolamnt" isn't a word in the English language, and I'm afraid I can't infer what you meant there. You asked how to ensure that the amount, which is a string in your object, is a number in the JSON. The above is how you do that.

Comment: okay i get it now . dolamnt was being shorten cause it is a variable "dolaramount" is what its meant.

Comment: correction sir . i'm sorry but the string wasn't an object . it's a general variable

Answer (score 0):

You can make amount field is `Number` then it will automatically convert to Number from string

```
amount:{
   type: Number
}
```

or you can use `parse.float` like

```
socket.on('dollar quest', function(dolquest,dolamnt,uid,stud,stat){
    var info = new InfoUser({
        username: stud,
        amount: parseFloat(dolamnt),
        question: dolquest
    });

    InfoUser.save(function(err,user){
        if(err)throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });
});
```

Comment: which one you tried ? N.B: should `Number` instead `number`

Comment: type:Number on my schema
and parseFloat(dolamnt), on the server side

Comment: When i try this it always says ```infousers validation failed```

Comment: you may trying to same `username` can try by different user name and try `InfoUser.save` like my code

Comment: sorry sir but i can't understand what you're saying

Comment: can try by different `username` if got duplicate `username` then will get error because your are using `index`

Comment: i tried it sir but still didn't work . any suggestion again?